# Detecting iframe content changes prior to server response

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Is it possible to detect when an iframe's content is about to change, such as when a request begins (the result of a user clicking a link within the iframe) but the server has not yet sent a response?

Background:

I've got a legacy web app that is consumed within a container that doesn't show loading statuses. This web app also uses an iframe to simulate a partial page loading. All navigation occurs within that iframe.

When a page within the iframe is loading, I display a loading animation on the iframe's parent page by monitoring the iframe's `onreadstatechange` event (IE only):

```
$('#iframe').on('readystatechange', function () {
    var state = this.readyState;

    (state === 'loading' || state === 'interactive') && $('#loading').show();
    state === 'complete' && $('#loading').hide();
});
```

This implementation has a significant limitation, however. The problem arises when there is a gap between when a request is made and when the web server responds.

For example, if the user clicks a link within the iframe that triggers some sort of long-running process, the status indicator animation does not display because the web server has not yet sent its response. The status indicator animation only shows after the server sends its response and the new page begins to load (where `readyState === 'loading'`).

So the net result is there are times when the user has no knowledge that anything is happening. In a typical web browser, when you click a link, a loading animation plays, even if the server is taking its time to respond. Because my web app is being contained within a WinForms WebBrowser control (and I don't have control of the WinForms app), there's no indication to the end user anything is happening.

Comment: Do you control pages within Iframe? Are they from the same domain as the parent?

Comment: Yes and yes. The iframe content is within the same domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both iframe pages and parent are of the same origin - they can communicate between each other. All you have to do is to attach handler to iframe contentWindow `onbeforeunload` event.

You would display "Loading..." in the  `onbeforeunload` event of contentWindow - since it happens before page begins navigating, and hide "Loading..." in iframe `onload` since it happens after.

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xga7Q/1/ click a link that takes some time to load (e.g. expand "Examples" and select any of examples.